# How to fix multiprocessing echo server to handle multiple clients

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-multiprocessing

I want to create a multiprocessing echo server. I am currently using telnet as my client to send messages to my echo server.Currently I can handle one telnet request and it echos the response. I initially, thought I should intialize the pid whenever I create a socket. Is that correct?

How do I allow several clients to connect to my server using multiprocessing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import os
from multiprocessing import Process

def create_socket():

    # Create socket
    sockfd = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Port for socket and Host
    PORT = 8002
    HOST = 'localhost'

    # bind the socket to host and port
    sockfd.bind((HOST, PORT))
    # become a server socket
    sockfd.listen(5)

    start_socket(sockfd)

def start_socket(sockfd):

    while True:

        # Establish and accept connections woth client
        (clientsocket, address) = sockfd.accept()

         # Get the process id.
        process_id = os.getpid()
        print("Process id:", process_id)

        print("Got connection from", address)
        # Recieve message from the client
        message = clientsocket.recv(2024)
        print("Server received: " + message.decode('utf-8'))
        reply = ("Server output: " + message.decode('utf-8'))
        if not message:
            print("Client has been disconnected.....")
            break
        # Display messags.
        clientsocket.sendall(str.encode(reply))

    # Close the connection with the client
    clientsocket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    process = Process(target = create_socket)     
    process.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a good idea to understand which are blocking system calls and which are not. `listen` for example is not blocking and `accept` is blocking one. So basically - you created one process through `Process(..)`, that blocks at the `accept` and when a connection is made - handles that connection.

Your code should have a structure - something like following (pseudo code)

```
def handle_connection(accepted_socket):
    # do whatever you want with the socket
    pass

def server():

    # Create socket and listen to it. 
    sock = socket.socket(....)
    sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    sock.listen(5)

    while True:
        new_client = sock.accept() # blocks here.

        # unblocked 
        client_process = Process(target=handle_connection, args=(new_client))
        client_process.start()
```

I must also mention, while this is a good way to just understand how things can be done, it is not a good idea to start a new process for every connection.

Comment: In the handle_connection() is where I would echo the message? So therfore, I don't need __main__ and where would I call client_process.start()

Comment: yeah in `handle_connection` you should echo the message. you can do `client_process.start` immediately

Comment: Also, Where would I put the os.getpid()?

Comment: Why do you want to put `os.getpid()`. `os.getpid()` - will return process ID of the current process. so whichever process you want `PID` of, you should put `os.getpid()` there. so if you want to know the `pid` of client process, put it in `handle_connection`

Comment: Ok I give up. For some reason when I connect them, when ever type a message they disconnect.

Comment: @pennyBoy Don't give up. When you get to the "For some reason" stage, the fun is beginning. You can see it on the horizon. :)

Answer (score 0):

The initial part of setting up the server, binding, listening etc (your `create_socket`) should be in the master process.

Once you `accept` and get a socket, you should spawn off a separate process to take care of that connection. In other words, your `start_socket` should be spawned off in a separate process and should loop forever.

Comment: It worked kinda. but now it seems to be blocking whenever I create a new process. I'll update my code.